# Print a string containing both unicode and html tags

Tags: php

I want to print a string containing both unicode and html tags.I am using `htmlentities()` to show the html tags. but it encodes the unicode too. How to solve it?

```
$str="മലയാളം <html>";
echo $str; ( shows മലയാളം )
$str=htmlentities($str);
echo $str; (shows à´®à´²à´¯à´¾à´³à´� <html>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform `htmlentities` what encoding your string is in, so it can treat it correctly:

```
$str = htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Or just use `htmlspecialchars` instead, which only encodes characters with a special meaning in HTML, like `<` and `&`, and leaves all other characters as is.